# re-deploying API Gateway on AWS causes ConflictException: Method already exists for this resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, aws-api-gateway, claudiajs

I have a set of API endpoints which was successfully deployed and re-deployed after several updates to the API endpoints.

However, an error occurred when both my colleague and I deployed the API resource at the same time.

When I tried to redeploy it again, it gave the error of Method already existing. I have checked all the methods and they are all unique.

I have also tried re-deploying to a new stage (test instead of the current dev) but it still gave the same error.

Comment: Have you checked using AWS CLI? Maybe console does not show everything in this case?

Comment: I used a deployment tool claudia.js and everything was working fine up till today. Not sure it AWS CLI would work though